# Idiom structure

Tags: idioms

I’ve got a problem with the usage of some idioms, which can be replaced by some simple words; I wanted to know that the structure remains the same or not? For example in this conditional statement:
“If I finished my tasks, I could rest.”
In this case, if I want to use “**if and it’s a big if**” as the simple “**if**” to emphasise more, will the structure remain the same?
“**If and it’s a big if** I finished my tasks, I could rest.”
Does it make sense?
Thank you so much

Comment: I would punctuate: **If,** and it’s a big **if,** I finished my tasks, I could rest. The words 'and it's a big if' may be omitted and are parenthetical, and you may see parentheses used: If (and it’s a big if) I finished my tasks, I could rest.

Comment: Thank you so much for your succinct explanation

Comment: For spoken English written down, don't use parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I think "If, and it’s a big if, I finished my tasks, I could rest" is correct and normal, but "If I finished my tasks, and that’s a big if, I could rest" sounds more natural to me. Just my opinion. Both are more or less the same.